# Could not resolve property exception for transient property

Tags: java, hibernate, hbase

I am trying to apply hibernate criteria on a class which contains a transient field(A list of objects). When I call criteria.list() it throws exception and says that it is not able to resolve that property as it does not have any mapping. I am applying Hibernate Restrictions only on few mapped fields. The partial structure of the class is like this:-

```
@Table(name = "table_records")

public class SampleClass implements Serializable {

public SampleClass(){
}

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "table_records_GEN")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "start_datetime")
private Date startDatetime;

@Column(name = "end_datetime")
private Date endDatetime;


@Transient
public List<SomeObject> records;
```

It contains many other fields as well. I am getting error on **records** field as it is transient. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. The Restriction was actually applied on the "records" field instead of a "totalRecords" field and as it was not able to find mapping, it threw exception.

Thanks to those whose tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing @Entity  from the main POJO

try it like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_records")
public class SampleClass implements Serializable
```

Comment: @Entity annotation is present. There is some other issue.

Comment: can you add your criteria implementation?

Comment: Yes. I can but when i call criteria.list() it throws exception.